# Is there a way to determine how socket to the connection?

Tags: java, user-interface, networking

WOndering count of determine a way there is one of the ways to determine

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way to determine how many connections are made to the socket?

No ... apart from counting them; i.e. counting the number of times that your application calls `accept` for the `ServerSocket` object.

As for the request of your question ... I can't figure out what you are actually asking.